# Cannot access file on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have a django project that worked perfectly on my local server returning a response. I am now trying to run it on pythonanywhere, it keeps saying no such directory or file. I initially used the `os.path.dirname("__file__")` but then I changed it into the absolute address, i.e. "/home/username/projectname/filename" to no avail. That latter method is the only one others on the web are suggesting, but it still isn't working. Is there a special syntax to access files in pythonanywhere? or do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

The following is the line that throws the error:

```
with open("home/<username>/<project>/layer.pem", "r") as rsa_priv_file:
```

Directory structure:
[image: Directory structure]

Comment: are you entering your actual username and project in the fields `<username>` and `<project>`?

Comment: you must have seen so much in this world :D, yes I am entering the real names.

Comment: Can you show your app's directory and file structure?

Comment: I just did, sorry I had to redact parts of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this `with open("home/<username>/<project>/layer.pem", "r") as rsa_priv_file:` 
is the actual code you're using, then you're missing a `/` at the beginning. What you're actually asking for with that code is not the absolute path to layer.pem, but a relative path rooted in the current directory.

Also, the `os.path.dirname("__file__")` is not working because you quoted the `__file__`. What you're asking for is the dirname of a file called "`__file__`" (which will be an empty string), not the dirname of the current file.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I will try, but in the __file__ case, it wouldnt work unless i quoted it on my local server.

Comment: It may "work" in the sense of not raising an exception, but it's not doing anything close to what you expect.

Comment: Correct, but i made sure im getting a return value, ie i checked it outside the function on a console. No quotes threw the undefined variable error anf with quotes it opened the file. May it be jupyter? Or windows? I am using 2.7.

Comment: Ah. In Jupyter, `__file__` is not defined. I'm not sure why they decided not to set it, but I guess there's a good reason.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you so much for your help, i will try your guidelines tonight.